# When Token Metadata Program was first deployed

Tags: rpc, metadata, ledger

I want to process all blocks which referenced `mpl_metadata_program` **in parallel**, which would mean that simply using `get_signatures_for_address` is insufficient as it would be hard to parallelize, so instead I decided to process `mpl_metadata_program` instructions in batches of 1000 or so slots (by using `get_signatures_for_address` inside them).

However, as another optimization, I understand that I do not need to process blocks from the genesis, as `mpl_metadata_program` was deployed somewhere in the future block, and the only question is when was it deployed (and another one is how to find it myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be faster to inspect all transactions referencing the whichever loader that program uses, looking for the earliest deploy instruction. Then you can index all blocks since that slot

Comment: For me the fastest solution was to use binary search in conjunction with `get_signatures_for_address`. This way I found out that `mpl-token-metadata` was first deployed at slot `81_096_360`.

Comment: maybe write that up as an answer